# "When this battle will be finally over" - shouldn't it be "When this battle is finally over"?

Tags: sentence-construction, future-time

I read something in the manga:

> When this battle will finally be over... take me out to eat some tasty yakiniku.

"when...will be" seems strange to me, isn't it better saying "When this battle is finally over"? Since this is translated from Japanese, I am not sure whether its grammar is correct or not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OP's is quite right. Clauses identifying a future time using ***when, after, before, as soon as, until***, etc. use present tense. Only the *main* clause (saying what *will* happen then) uses future tense.

Look at these examples from [Ege Academy...](http://www.egeacademy.com/blog/exercises/future-time-clauses-when-before-after-as-soon-as-until/)

> *When I **finish** writing the reports, I **will go** out with my friends.*
>   *When the party **is** over, we**’ll clean** the house.*
>   *After her sister **prepares** dinner, they**’ll invite** their neighbours.*
>   *My father **will buy** a new car after he **saves** enough money.*
>   etc., etc.

Comment: +1 alternatively, "When this battle **is** finally over... take me out to eat some tasty yakiniku."

Comment: @TylerH: Since English can use "present tense" for future actions, that could equally well be *When it's over you **are taking** me out...* But it's worth noting that if I did something like that with the first example above, *When I finish writing the reports, I **go** out with my friends* would normally be understood to be talking about a *habitual* (past, present, *and* future) thing that I usually do after writing reports.

Comment: But isn't it possible to say, "I'll take you out to eat some tasty yakiniku tomorrow, when this battle will finally be over"? If the previous sentence is possible, why?

Comment: @sumelic Very good example. It's acceptable because the main clause is in the future, and then dependent clause is expressing something relative to that.

Comment: Depending on the formality of the source (this particular one seems to be rather informal, but Japanese can get extremely formal), "when this battle *be over*" might actually be accurate.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, this is strange, and I think you're probably correct in diagnosing it as a translation flub. It's the kind of use I often hear from non-native speakers.

Answer (score 2):

In the Japanese language, there are 2 main tenses. One for actions that are done/finished (past) and another for those that aren't done yet (present and future). They simply specify time counters to indicate when an action took/takes/will take place. We can presume that the person who translated the manga just had a lapse of judgment here, re: choice between present and future tense.